# Magento 2 API GET comment field from Aheadworks One Step Checkout extension?

Tags: magento2, rest-api

We are using the AheadWorks One Step Checkout extension in our Magento 2 Shop.
Our problem is that in the Magento2 API

```
https://www.shop.com/rest/V1/orders/12345
```

The comment field is not activated by Aheadworks and they write they have no solution.

I even looked into

```
/V1/orders/:id/comments
```

But that is only showing the order comments which is something completly different.

So how could I retrieve the order comments?

Comment: You'll have to add API functionality to their module.

Comment: How? Please help.